# How to set auto align in Prettier for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, alignment, prettier

I really like how Prettier/Python and other extensions works in VSC but I want to add settings to auto align or align by selecting code:

[https://github.com/WarWithinMe/better-align/raw/master/images/2.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7nzu.png)

I tried Better Align extension but the result is beeing overwritten by Prettier.

Comment: Same here. Being overwritten by autopep8 or black or YAPF

Answer (score -1):

Put

```
// prettier-ignore
```

above the area you want prettier to ignore.

Comment: This is not a solution for "auto align".

Comment: answer seems wrong